# find average of input to vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, average

I am trying to write a program where the user inputs as many numbers as they want and then the program returns the average of the numbers. So far the program only outputs the last number entered.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>


using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    vector<float> v;
    int input;

    cout << " Please enter numbers you want to find the mean of:" <<endl;
    while (cin >> input);
    v.push_back(input);

float average = accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0/ v.size());
cout << "The average is" << average << endl;

return 0;  

}
```

Comment: I think you've got the Maths wrong. And the data type is strange too.

Comment: @NickyC To find the average of a set of number you do the sum of the numbers divided by how many there are don't you? and my program just seems to return the last number entered.

Comment: @noodlebar: you code is messed up, you put /v.size() in the wrong place, it looks like you just copy paste it from somewhere.

Comment: What @swang say is where you get the Maths wrong.

Comment: @noodlebar Put it after the `)` of `std::accumulate`.

Comment: @noodlebar: have you read mine and other's answer?

Comment: @noodlebar Do you realize your code (which is wrong) mismatches your understanding of average (which is correct)?

Comment: @swang Thank you both, the code now works, i have changed it to double instead of float, and debugged it. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Is the vector (or storing of the values) a requirement?  An average of items doesn't need to store the items; only sum their values and count the items.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In **C++17 and higher**, you should **prefer [`std::reduce`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)** over [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). Both calculate the sum, but `std::reduce` has higher numerical stability and, less importantly, is potentially faster because it might be parallelized.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

float average(std::vector<float> const& v){
    if(v.empty()){
        return 0;
    }

    auto const count = static_cast<float>(v.size());
    return std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end()) / count;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<float> v{8, 4, 2, 7, 5};
    auto const a = average(v);
    std::cout << "average: " << a << "\n";
}
```

Note that `static_cast` suppresses a compile warning here, that `std::size_t` (the type of `v.size()`) with 8 byte size can theoretically express values for which the precision of a 4 byte `float` is not sufficient.

---

Your code has two bug. First get rid of semi-colon after `while`

```cpp
while (cin >> input); // <-- bug
v.push_back(input);   // not in loop

// fixed loop
while (cin >> input){
    v.push_back(input);
}
```

Second your average calculation is wrong. The third argument of `std::accumulate` is the *initial value* of the sum, which is `0` by default, so you don't need to pass it.

Your actual bug is, that you divided the 0 by the element count. What you wanted, was to divide the value sum by the element count.

```cpp
float average = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0 / v.size());
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

// fixed code
float average = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) / v.size();

// without explicit init value
float average = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end()) / v.size();

// C++17 version with higher numerical stability
float average = reduce(v.begin(), v.end()) / v.size();
```

Also, the element of container data type *should* match the container type or if your really want to read integers and add to a `float` vector, you should use `static_cast`. The bulky syntax not only suppresses any compiler warnings, but also makes it clear that this is not an oversight, but an intentional difference in data types.

```cpp
vector<float> v; // float vector
int input;       // integer input value
// ...
v.push_back(input); // add int value to float container

// an intentional type conversion should catch the eye
v.push_back(static_cast<float>(input));
```

Comment: And then someone will try to find the average of an empty range... boom!

Comment: @Tom Updated the post.

Comment: Note of caution - should std::reduce cause you to exceed int max - it will wrap - and your average will be wrong (not as pertinent for int as you'd need to go some to reach max - but if you use this for char....)

Comment: It wont help if exceeding int max - but if using std::vector<char> v; can use  std::reduce(v.begin(), v.end(), int(0)); to force int addition before creating the average

Comment: What `const&` means on `float average(std::vector<float> const& v){`? Is it the same as `float average(const std::vector<float>& v){`?

Answer (score 13):

There are quite a few bugs in your code, have you actually debugged it? here's a working version:

```
#include <vector>                                                               
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <numeric>                                                              


using namespace std;                                                            

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    vector<float> v;                                                            
    float input;                                                                

    cout << " Please enter numbers you want to find the mean of:" <<endl;       
    while (cin >> input)                                                        
        v.push_back(input);                                                     

    float average = accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0)/v.size();              
    cout << "The average is" << average << endl;                                

    return 0;                                                                   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The third argument to [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is the *initial* value, so you start with `0.0 / v.size()` (which is very small) and then add all items in the vector.

Instead you should use a value of zero as initial value, and after you calculated the total of all values in the vector *then* you divide by the size.

And as others pointed out, you only add the last value to the vector.

Comment: 0.0 / v.size() is not just very small, it is either 0 or undefined :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector_name.size() to get the number of elements in vector. Here's my attempt for to compute average:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>

   //function to compute average
   double compute_average(std::vector<int> &vi) {

     double sum = 0;

     // iterate over all elements
     for (int p:vi){

        std::cout << "p is " << p << std::endl;
        sum = sum + p;
     }

     return (sum/vi.size());
    }

    int main(){

        std::vector <int>vi =  {5,10};
        double val;

        val = compute_average(vi);

        std::cout << "avg is " << val << std::endl;
        return 0;   
    }
```